# Designing a new Operation System

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel

I want to design a new OS to learn more about how an OS works. This OS is only for educational purpose and I had a few doubts choosing its kernel.

- Is there any legal issue for using an Ubuntu kernel?
- Should I use an Ubuntu Supported kernel source, a mainline kernel source or simply a Linux kernel source? (I thought choosing Supported Ubuntu Kernel would be best as I'd get a lot of hardware driver support with it)
- Assuming that I succeeded in designing an OS with Ubuntu Kernel(mainline or supported), can I call it Linux <"whatever-name-I'll-come-up-with"> or would it just be called a modified Ubuntu?

Comment: One small additional comment: hardware support does not only depend on the kernel but also on some userspace programs & configuration, e.g. udev, bluez, etc.

Comment: I thought Ubuntu had a Linux kernel?  What do you mean by "Ubuntu kernel"?

Comment: @Wildcard : Yes, Ubuntu does have a linux kernel but it uses Ubuntu patches and drivers.( Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linux kernel source in Ubuntu](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/) is open source, so there is no problem with using (parts of) it, just like you can use any other linux kernel source.

Using the Ubuntu name for your OS is not allowed unless you have permission from Canonical (who own the [Ubuntu trademark](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy#your-use-of-our-trademarks)), which in general is true for any other trademarks and their owners too.  Of course you could mention that your kernel is based on the Ubuntu (or Red Hat, or any other) kernel if that's true.

In other words “Whatever”, “Whatever OS” & “Whatever Linux” are all fine (provided you actually use a linux kernel in case of the latter one), but calling it “Ubuntu Whatever” is probably not okay.

Comment: For the kind of operating system I mentioned, can I call it Linux abcd or do I have to call it Ubuntu Based Linux abcd(Which is technically correct but sounds like I didn't put much effort as it is **Ubuntu based** )?

Comment: @7_R3X see my update; using Ubuntu in the name is only allowed with written permission from Canonical (there are some exceptions if you just make a remix: an installer image that only uses original Ubuntu packages, but with a different default selection).